# Android - cannot screen on service for Alert Dialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I want to alert dialog which can just turn on phone when phone is lock and appears on device.
Here is my code:

**Service.java:**

```
public static void popupDialog()
{
    Handler h = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
    h.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (CustomMainActivity.mWindow != null)
            {
                     CustomMainActivity.mWindow.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
            }
            final View view = View.inflate(context.getApplicationContext(),R.layout.popup, null);
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setView(view);
            final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder1.create();
            final ImageButton Imageback = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.Imageback);
            Imageback.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR);
            alertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

**CustomMainActivity.java:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
        mWindow = getWindow();
.
.
.
}
```

Now , Although it can show on phone , it is still cannot turn device awake. Any suggestion?

Comment: you question is not clear. what do you want to achieve actually??? please clear the scenario

Comment: @ZahanSafallwa I edited my question.